# ReferenceError в QML

Tags: qt, qml

В Sample.ui.qml файле есть компонент Transform, в нем пытаюсь задать значение rotation

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Qt3D.Core 2.0

Item {
    property alias t: t
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Transform{
        id: t
        rotation: fromAxesAndAngles(1,1,1,90);
    }

}
```

При этом код не собирается, ибо ошибка:

> Функции не поддерживаются в форме QtQuick UI

Пытаюсь вынести присвоение значение rotation в Sample.qml файл:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import Qt3D.Core 2.0

TstForm {
    t.rotation: fromAxesAndAngles(1,1,1,90);

}
```

При этом получаю ошибку

> qrc:/Sample.qml:6: ReferenceError: fromAxesAndAngles is not defined

Как правильно использовать функции/методы классов в QML?

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае убери .ui из имени файла - тогда файл станет не QtQuick UI, а QML и можно будет писать функции.

Или попробуй задать значение через редактор интерфейса мышкой.

Во втором случае `t.rotation: Transform.fromAxesAndAngles(1,1,1,90);`